# Retain ID references when tokenizing record using generator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, token, generator

I am trying to duplicate the (very cool) datamatching approach described [here](http://nadbordrozd.github.io/blog/2016/07/22/datamatching-part-2-spark-pipeline/) using pandas.  The goal is to take component parts (tokens) of a record and use to match to another df.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to retain the source ID and associate with individual tokens.  Hoping someone here has a clever suggestion for how I could do this.  I searched Stack but was not able to find a similar question.

Here is some sample data and core code to illustrate.  This takes a dataframe, tokenizes select columns, generates token, token type, and id (but ID part does not work):

```
d = {'Id': [3,6], 'Org_Name': ['Acme Co Inc.', 'Buy Cats Here LLC'], 'Address': ['123 Hammond Lane', 'Washington, DC 20456']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def tokenize_name(name):
    if isinstance(name, basestring) is True:
        clean_name = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() else ' ' for c in name)
        return clean_name.lower().split()
    else:
        return name

def tokenize_address(address):
    if isinstance(address, basestring) is True:
        clean_name = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() else ' ' for c in address)
        return clean_name.lower().split()
    else:
        return address

left_tokenizers = [
    ('Org_Name', 'name_tokens', tokenize_name),
    ('Address', 'address_tokens', tokenize_address)
]

#this works except for ID references
def prepare_join_keys(df, tokenizers):
    for source_column, key_name, tokenizer in tokenizers:
        for index in df.index:
            if source_column in df.columns:
                for record in df[source_column]:
                    if isinstance(record, float) is False:
                        for token in tokenizer(record):
                            yield (token, key_name, df.iloc[index]['Id'])

for item in prepare_join_keys(df, left_tokenizers):
    print item
```

This code yields correct tokens but yields Id values for ALL tokens, instead of the corresponding ID value only.  I know what I have here is wrong, but I can't think of a way to do this using my generator function.  Desired output would be:

```
acme, name_tokens, 3
co, name_tokens, 3
inc, name_tokens, 3
buy, name_tokens, 6
cats, name_tokens, 6
here, name_tokens, 6
llc, name_tokens, 6
123, address_tokens, 3
hammond, address_tokens, 3
etc.
```

Comment: I realize that what I have here is literally appending the Id column and index from the df for each token.  Need to find a way to insert the Id only along with each corresponding token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the index of the `Id`, not in a dedicated `for` loop, but at the same time you get a new record. I would suggest something like:

```
def prepare_join_keys(df, tokenizers):
    for source_column, key_name, tokenizer in tokenizers:
        # for index in df.index:
        if source_column in df.columns:
            for index, record in enumerate(df[source_column]):
                if isinstance(record, float) is False:
                    for token in tokenizer(record):
                        yield (token, key_name, df.iloc[index]['Id'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It seems enumerate was the method I was missing.